# if window.location.href.indexOf('player=1') add style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to add style if my site url= http://example.com/?player=1
then I found that code but I can't use it
If url= http://example.com/?player=1 body style will be

```
body{ background:#000; }

<script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[
  var curl = window.location.href;
  if (curl.indexOf('player=1') != -1) {
    curl = curl.replace('player=1', 'm=0');
    window.location.href = curl;
  }
  //]]>
</script>
```

it replace player=1 with m=0 but i need to use it to add style

Comment: What do you mean by "add style"?  You need to explain what you're trying to do

Comment: sorry your question is unclear. what style are you talking about?

Comment: i mean if the url http://example.com/?player=1

Comment: style will be body{background;#000}

Comment: You want to add style to body only, if there is `m=0` in the URL with javascript?

Comment: `if(window.location.search == "?player=1") { $('body').addClass('new-background'); //or $('body').css('background','#000'); }`

Comment: i can't use this code
then i need help to make body code change to body{background:#000;}

Comment: You shouldn't be programmatically adding style based on a URL. It should be independent of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `style` of the body element if the string you are checking for is present in the URL.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("player=1")!=-1)
    document.body.style.backgroundColor="#000";
```

Alternatively, to avoid setting inline styles, you can create a new class and apply it to the body if the string you are checking for is present.

```
body.player1{
    background:#000;
}

if(window.location.href.indexOf("player=1")!=-1)
    document.body.classList.add("player1");
```

Answer (score 3):

add this in your script

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("example.com/?player=1") > -1){
  $('body').css("background-color","#000");
}
```

---

manipulating your own code would be like below.

```
 var curl = window.location.href;
  if (curl.indexOf('player=1') != -1) {
   $('body').css("background-color","#000");
  }
```

Comment: i use blog and i need it for all links in blog

Comment: @compulack you must make sure you run the above script in all your pages..

Comment: why doesn't it work with 'player=1' alone?

Comment: @Mike it will work with `player=1` alone too..

Comment: i use it but not any thing happend

Comment: @compulack copy the above code and paste it and run in your browser console window on the page you want the change to happen on..

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   //<![CDATA[
       var curl = window.location.href;
       if (curl.indexOf('player=1') != -1) {
           document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"
       }
   //]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of regex of JS.

[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/xupidiqolu/edit?html,css,js,output)

Here is code (HTML) -

```
<p>compu lack, Your styling is based on URL string</p>
```

CSS -

```
.dynamic-css {
   display: inline-block;
  background: tomato;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = /jsbin/.test(window.location.href);
  if (url) {
    console.log("Found 'StackOverflow in URL. I will add Style to text now.'")
    $('p').addClass('dynamic-css');
  }
});
```